# Using another query in mysql column

Tags: mysql

I want to write a mysql query like the below way.Can I use the TABLE1.Id in the columns when doing the another column query. If not how can i achieve the samething

```
SELECT COL1,COL2, (SELECT COL3 FROM TABLE2 WHERE ID=TABLE1.ID LIMIT 1)  AS COL3
  FROM TABLE1;
```

Comment: why you don't use join then use where clause, it same acctually !

Comment: just remove as and your query will run

Comment: Thanks a lot will remove as and  try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join` should help you:

```
SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3
  FROM TABLE1 join Table2 on table1.id = table2.id;
```

Comment: Have some complicate inner join so want to use  the query  in the column.  Thanks for the info